# Understanding linked list code and how to fix it from moving the head?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to figure out how to use linked lists and i'm sort of understanding, however i've ran into an error. I used a youtube tutorial which was good, however he did not explain this code and I copied it from him and tried to understand it at my own pace, however I cannot really understand why it works this way and how to fix it.

```
            if(firstnode == 0){
            temp = addtolist(request2);
            head = temp;
            firstnode++;
            }
            else{
            temp = addtolist(request2);
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
            }
```

Add to list code

```
            linkedlist *addtolist(char value[]){
            linkedlist *result = malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
            strcpy(result->data,value);
            result->next = NULL;
            return result;
            }
```

Firstnode is simply an integer to check whether or not the user has created a node or not. And request2 is just the value that i wish to store in the node. I am wondering as to how to get my linked list to be in the proper order when i print it, as i am moving the head everytime, what can I do to prevent this and link the list properly? Sorry if its a dumb question but I can't seem to understand how this works.

Comment: A couple of examples may help [Singly Linked List of Strings With Sorted Insertion](https://pastebin.com/PechfyQa) and then for additional list operations you can adapt from [Singly Linked List](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB). When asking questions, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: First of all I'd suggest you format your code properly. And if the youtube tutorial (which one BTW) showS poorly formatted code like yours, find another one. Also we can't tell much about your code because most of the relevant code is missing. Reas this [MCVE].

Comment: It's easy to insert at the beginning of a singly-linked list, and that's what the code does. To insert at the end, you either need to maintain a tail pointer, or you need to walk the list to find the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this code you implement something like a FIFO list (you move the had every time you add a node), you can check what FIFO is here:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)

If I'm understanding correctly you are trying to implement a LIFO list

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

In the following code, I saved the head, and I used a tail node for adding new nodes.

```
    if (firstnode == 0) {
        temp = addtolist(request2);
        head = temp;
        tail = head;
        firstnode++;
    }
    else {
        temp = addtolist(request2);
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
```